# How do I enable the eqeqeq rule in my eslintrc.json?

Tags: javascript, json, eslint

```
 .eslintrc.json
    {
        "env": {
            "browser": true
        },
        "extends": "eslint:recommended",
        "rules": {
            "no-console": 0,
            "eqeqeq": 2,
            "accessor-pairs": "error",
            "array-bracket-spacing": "error",
            "array-callback-return": "error",
            "arrow-body-style": "error",
    ...
    }



     practice.js
        'Use strict';

        var x = 1;
        var y = '2';
        if(x == y) {
          console.log('Exist');
        }else {
          console.log('Not Exist');
        }
```

I am trying to get eslint to throw an error for not using the "===" and I believe I am using the correct syntax to add the rule in my  eslintrc.json  file, however, no errors are being reported in my code.

(I am new to code and eslint, so sorry if I missed this answer somewhere else.)

Answer (score 0):

Try switching `eqeqeq:2` to `eqeqeq:"error"`
2 and error should do the same thing but that's my best guess to your problem. You could also try adding the always option to see if that works. `eqeqeq: ["error", "always" ]`

I would also consider it a good practice to either use all number codes or all text codes in your rule file to make the code a little easier to read.